# Need information from app for test to use

Tags: cypress

Using a canvas and want to test mouse operations so need our graphics library Konva to return me the info for use in a mouse move.

This silly code illustrates I want to get hold of the Konva.names result but obviously this doesn't work.

```
    let names = "no names";
    cy.document()
      .then((doc) => {
          let scriptTag = doc.createElement("script");
          scriptTag.textContent = "names = Konva.names";
          doc.children[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
          console.log(names);
      });
```

I feel like I need some kind of Cypress extension that exposes Konva interactions to the test.
 Where do I start with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Cypress isn't really designed for reading and using data (ie scraping) although you can do some things with it. I have a case where one test script reads some data, and then stores it in a fixtures file, which another test then uses. I can provide more detail if you want it

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I will plan to follow this flow:

* create data for canvas
* load app with data.
* load test with data.
* perform test clicks on canvas based on the data.

I feel like this couples my tests to the canvas x,y coords more than I would like, but it will work.

Comment: Ended up choosing to use cy.request to pull the data from the server during the test. Made it easier to get the information I wanted. Cut down on data seeding time. Remove need to correlate seed data with test scenario. 

Feels better now to have to mess with the app under test during the test.